# Find the maximum sum of all contiguous subarrays and not consecutive each others which its length at most 'k' in a given array

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Problem: Given an array 'arr' and an integer 'k', find the maximum sum of all subarrays of 'arr' whose size is at most 'k'. Note that you can't choose subarrays which are consecutive or overlap each other.

Constraints:
0 <= `arr.size()` <= 10^5;
0 <= `arr[i]` <= 10^5;
1 <= k <= 10^5;

For example:

1. `arr = [1, 10, 7, 3, 4]` and `k = 1`. The answer will be 14.
   Explanation: We can only choose subarrays of 1 size, so we will choose [10] and [4], sum of them is 14. You can't choose [10],[7],[4] because [10] and [7] are consecutive subarrays.
2. `arr = [15 9 11 11 1 12 18 18 18 8 1]` and `k = 3`. The answer should be 94
   Explanation: Subarrays are [15], [11, 11], [12, 18], [18, 8, 1], These sums are 94.

This is an update of the [House Robber](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber) problem  and can be easily solved using dynamic programming:

`dp[i] = max(dp[i-2] + arr[i], dp[i-1])`

I can solve this problem by adding one more dimension into the dynamic array:

`dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-2][j-1] + arr[i], dp[i-1][k])`

But the problem is that above solution will exceed the time limit for worst case scenario: k = 10^5 and arr.size() = 10^5. It also runs very slow even when k = 10^4 and arr.size() = 10^4 because the time complexity is O(n*k).

I have tried to remove the smallest value from a subarray starting with arr[0:k+1], and then continue to remove in arr(j+1:j+k+1) (j is the index of removed value) but it goes wrong somewhere.

Is there any way to reduce the time complexity for this solution?

Thank you for spending your time.

Comment: Can I get some clarification? Why do you not select any sub-arrays of length 3 in the the second example?  Why do you choose 2 sub arrays in the first example and 4 in the second example.

The problem is not clearly worded. I can think of two reasonable interpretations of it, but neither one fits your examples

Comment: Sorry for unclear questions. The problem should be "find the maximum sum of all subarrays that its size at most 'k' in 'arr' and these subarray can't consecutive the previous one". I will edit the question later.

Comment: Are you using any particular programming language?

Comment: I'm not using particular programming language to represent any commands above.

Comment: Or you could minimize the holes, which appear at least every `n`?

Comment: @Neil did you mean every 'k'? I did remove the smallest number of every k, I also calculate the smallest sum in every k + 2 number (eg: [2,4,5,3], k = 2. I will calculate arr[i] + arr[i+k+1] and then compare it with every number in the middle subarray [4, 5]. If there is any number that is smaller than the sum, I will remove it. Otherwise, I will remove arr[i] and arr[i+k+1]). But none of these idea passed all the test cases. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: Oh right, `k`. I was just seeing the problem from another perspective; I don't think it should matter which problem statement you go with if the answer is correct. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but can you explain why you think the dimensionality of the House Robber problem is less?

Comment: @Neil The idea of House Robber is to check the max profits of rob this house, or not to rob this house and rob the next house. In this problem, we can't choose two consecutive subarrays and the size of subarrays cant exceed 'k', Which is the same as House Robber problem when 'k' = 1. The only different thing in this problem is that we have to deal with 'k'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the dimension, then use the idea of an optimal fringe.

First, as @Neil suggested, it is easier to minimize the holes. Each hole must be within `k+1` of the previous one. We will do that by keeping an array `best_holes` of pairs `(index of last hole, sum of holes)`. It starts with a fake element `(-1, 0)` representing a hole before the start of the array.

We don't need to keep track of the possibility of keeping a hole if we can do as well or better by placing a later one.

We also drop best holes when they are too much earlier to not have another hole after them.

Here is `O(n)` code.

```
from collections import deque

def best_sum (ary, k):
    best_holes = deque([(-1, 0)])
    for i in range(len(ary)):
        # Value of a hole at i plus the best best hole.
        value = ary[i] + best_holes[0][1]

        # Get rid of best_holes that this is better than.
        while value <= best_holes[-1][1]:
            best_holes.pop()

        # Record this best hole.
        best_holes.append((i, value))

        # Get rid of the best hole if it is too old to be used directly.
        if k < i - best_holes[0][0]:
            best_holes.popleft()

    return sum(ary) - best_holes[0][1]

print(best_sum([1, 10, 7, 3, 4], 1))
print(best_sum([15, 9, 11, 11, 1, 12, 18, 18, 18, 8, 1], 3))
```

If you want to know which arrays made up the sum, just use the following linked list trick:

```
def best_arrays (ary, k):
    best_holes = deque([(-1, 0, None)])
    for i in range(len(ary)):
        # Value of a hole at i plus the best best hole.
        value = ary[i] + best_holes[0][1]

        # Get rid of best_holes that this is better than.
        while value <= best_holes[-1][1]:
            best_holes.pop()

        # Record this best hole.
        best_holes.append((i, value, best_holes[0]))

        # Get rid of the best hole if it is too old to be used directly.
        if k < i - best_holes[0][0]:
            best_holes.popleft()

    answer = []
    i = len(ary)
    best_hole = best_holes[0]
    while -1 < i:
        if best_hole[0] + 1 < i:
            answer.append(ary[best_hole[0]+1 : i])
        i = best_hole[0]
        best_hole = best_hole[2]
    return list(reversed(answer))
```

Comment: (Voted up) does this assume positive numbers?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Nope. In the case of a negative number you'll just find that making the latest thing a hole is the best `best_hole`, and it is not too old to be used directly.